# Chrome and IE caching .htaccess redirects, Safari doesn't

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, internet-explorer, redirect

I have a simple redirect in an .htaccess to check and see if a user is authenticated. If not, we redirect them to our SSO for login.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
  RewriteCond %{ENV:AH_Client_IP} ^123\..*
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*SSESS.*$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/saml_login
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://saml.com?providerid=saml [L,R]
```

The problem is that the redirect is being cached in Chrome and IE. Safari is doing okay. Any thoughts on how I can prevent this caching?

Comment: I've never tried, but I suppose sending the right caching headers prior to the redirect should do the trick

Comment: probably it's a 301 redirect, and safari is being WRONG by not cacheing it. 301 = "gone permanently, here's the new location". there is NO point in retrying a URL that gave a 301, because you've been told it's permanently gone.  Force a 302 instead: `[L,R=302]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for anyone who finds this in the future.

Varnish was setting cache headers on the redirects.

IE and Chrome will cache 302s with cache headers on. You have to explicitly tell them not to cache the 302 via HTTP no-cache or expires headers.